# change loop select direction

Tags: modeling

Is there a simple trick to select loop faces in the direction I want. I'm trying to select the ring of faces and when I select the face in the red circle in the first photo it will select up and down, but when I use alt click on the face just below it then it will select the faces going left and right which is the direction I'm wanting.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your cursor close to the edge that will determine the direction of the face ring selection, if you put it close to the vertical edge the ring selection will be along horizontal and vice versa.

Comment: ohhh, that's cool. Thank you for that. I figured there was some cool trick that could select the ones I need in the direction I'm wanting.